# Swap out button once input field is clicked-into

Tags: jquery, button, textinput

I am trying to reverse-engineer some pre-existing code I found out there, and am running into trouble.

I want a button to change from saying "Skip" to "Enter" once the user clicks their cursor into the form field next to it.  So on first view they see "Skip" but once they start typing the button changes to "Enter"

```
<input type="text" id="visitor-name-input" placeholder="what's your name?">
<a id="skip-btn" href="#"><img src="skipbtn.png" height="50px"/></a>
<a id="enter-btn" href="#"><img src="enterbtn.png" height="50px" /></a>
```

So I'm wondering what kind of jQuery would result in swapping out `skip-btn` and `enter-btn` based on when `visitor-name-input` is clicked?  Some kind of toggle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `focus()` method when a user clicks into the text box

HTML (Changed to buttons to not worry about your images)

```
<input type="text" id="visitor-name-input" placeholder="what's your name?">
<button id="skip-btn" href="#">Skip</button>
```

jQuery

```
$( "#visitor-name-input" ).focus(function() {
  $('#skip-btn').text('Enter');
});
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/03cn2u9L/)

For you to still use your images then you can just have 1 link and replace the inner img `src` value

```
$( "#visitor-name-input" ).focus(function() {
  $('#skip-btn img').attr('src', 'enterbtn.png');
});
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/03cn2u9L/1/)

Comment: Thank you!  That's just what I had to do to make it work :)

Comment: Glad it worked out. Don't forget to choose as answer :)